# tests get HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException only when suite is run

Tags: java, spring

I am new to Spring development and trying to learn. Installed Netbeans 11.1 and cloned this [git repository](https://github.com/juleswhite/mobile-cloud-asgn1) and trying to get this VideoController to pass.

I am surprised why testAddGetVideo() test fails when run in a group but passes when run individually. [The test suite is here](https://github.com/juleswhite/mobile-cloud-asgn1/blob/master/src/test/java/org/magnum/dataup/AutoGradingTest.java). Struggling over it for a couple of days. Read thru SO and other posts.

**testAddGetVideo fails in test suite** but individual test passes (scroll down to see below)

[image: testAddGetVideo fails in test suite]

In the stack trace there is a

`org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException`

testAddGetVideo():

```
@Test
public void testAddGetVideo() throws Exception {
    videoSvc.addVideo(video);
    Collection<Video> stored = videoSvc.getVideoList();
    assertTrue(stored.contains(video));
}
```

My VideoController methods invoked by it:

```
/**
 * getVideos
 *
 * @return Collection<Video>
 */
@RequestMapping(value = VIDEO_SVC_PATH, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody Collection<Video> getVideos(HttpServletResponse response) {
    System.out.println("---------------getVideos---------------");
    System.out.println(videos.size() + " videos");
    System.out.println("===================");
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.setStatus(200);
    return videos.values();
}

/**
 * newVideo
 *
 * @param v
 * @return Video
 */
@RequestMapping(value = VIDEO_SVC_PATH, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody Video newVideo(@RequestBody Video v) {
    System.out.println("---------------newVideo---------------");

    checkAndSetId(v);
    String url = getDataUrl(v.getId());
    v.setDataUrl(url);

    videos.put(v.getId(), v);
    System.out.println("video " + v.getId() + " at " + v.getDataUrl());
    System.out.println("===================");
    return v;
}
```

VideoSvc

```
public static final String VIDEO_SVC_PATH = "/video";

public static final String VIDEO_DATA_PATH = VIDEO_SVC_PATH + "/{id}/data";

/**
 * This endpoint in the API returns a list of the videos that have
 * been added to the server. The Video objects should be returned as
 * JSON. 
 * 
 * To manually test this endpoint, run your server and open this URL in a browser:
 * http://localhost:8080/video
 * 
 * @return
 */
@GET(VIDEO_SVC_PATH)
public Collection<Video> getVideoList();

/**
 * This endpoint allows clients to add Video objects by sending POST requests
 * that have an application/json body containing the Video object information. 
 * 
 * @return
 */
@POST(VIDEO_SVC_PATH)
public Video addVideo(@Body Video v);
```

LOG:

```
---------------newVideo---------------
video 1 at http://localhost:8080/video/1/data
===================
---------------uploadVideo---------------
1 for video 1 data data
===================
---------------downloadVideo---------------
1 for video 1
===================
---------------newVideo---------------
video 2 at http://localhost:8080/video/2/data
===================
```

> > FAILS HERE TRANSMITTING THE VIDEOS

```
---------------getVideos---------------
2 videos
===================
---------------uploadVideo---------------

-9223372036854775808 for non existent video
```

sending invalid id -9223372036854775808 is part of the test.

getVideos() fails. (ordering of log output is skewed)

```
2019-09-09 14:50:28.988  WARN 16804 --- [tp1776486598-21] org.eclipse.jetty.server.Response        : Committed before 406 null
2019-09-09 14:50:28.988  WARN 16804 --- [tp1776486598-21] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Handling of [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException] resulted in Exception

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Committed
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Response.resetBuffer(Response.java:1242)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Response.sendError(Response.java:567)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Response.sendError(Response.java:544)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver.handleHttpMediaTypeNotAcceptable(DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver.java:246)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver.doResolveException(DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver.java:119)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.resolveException(AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerExceptionResolverComposite.resolveException(HandlerExceptionResolverComposite.java:75)
```

...STACK TRACE CONTINUES...

But when I immediately run the individual test without restarting the server, it passes.

```
---------------newVideo---------------
video 3 at http://localhost:8080/video/3/data
===================
---------------getVideos---------------
3 videos
===================
```

**individual test passes**

[image: individual test passes]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why, but the change below fixed it. The problem may have been with the automated test.

```
@Test
public void testGetNonExistantVideosData() throws Exception {

    long nonExistantId = getInvalidVideoId();

    try{
        Response r = videoSvc.getData(nonExistantId);
        assertEquals(404, r.getStatus());
    }catch(RetrofitError e){
        assertEquals(404, e.getResponse().getStatus());
    }
}
```

My method signature is below. **I changed the method to return null when an invalid id is passed in as parameter, and return the VideoStatus only when a valid id is passed in and the binary video mpeg data is successfully written to the HttpServletResponse.Outputstream**.

**In other words, doing a `response.sendError()` also requires a `return null;`.**

```
   @RequestMapping(value = VIDEO_DATA_PATH, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody VideoStatus uploadVideo(@PathVariable("id") long id, @RequestParam("data") MultipartFile data, HttpServletResponse response) {
        VideoStatus status = new VideoStatus(VideoStatus.VideoState.READY);
```